# How do you put a UIWebView somewhere other than MainView.xib?

Tags: iphone, sdk, uiwebview

I've been trying to put a `UIWebView` into my app, which is tableview based.

When the user selects a row, I want the new xib to load, but this one with a `UIWebView` on it.

From all of the tutorials I've seen, you can only put a `UIWebView` on the `MainView.xib`.

Can someone please tell me how to put a FUNCTIONING `UIWebView` somewhere other than the main view?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

You can put a UIWebView in any XIB you want. Why do you believe that it has to be in MainView.xib? Tutorials generally put everything in MainView.xib because they're keeping things simple. What problem are you having when you put it elsewhere?

Can you give a link to the tutorial that indicates that you have to put this in MainView? Can you describe what "doesn't work" actually means? Does it fail to display, fail to make callbacks, fail to load pages, render incorrect?